# MySQL: export multiple tables to CSV file

Tags: mysql, csv

I'm trying to export multiple MySQL tables into a single CSV file, these tables have different number of columns and have nothing in common. An example is below:

table1:

```
ID|    Name
1 |    Ted
2 |    Marry
null|    null
```

table2:

```
Married|    Age    |    Phone
Y      |    35     |    No
N      |    25     |    Yes
Y      |    45     |    No
```

The result that I want to get is:

```
ID|    Name  |   Married    |    Age    |     Phone
1 |    Ted   |   Y          |    35     |     No
2 |    Marry |   N          |    25     |     Yes
null|  null  |   Y          |    45     |     No
```

Is it possible to do using MySQL commands? I have tried all types of `join` but it doesn't give me the result that I need.

Comment: Does `table2` also contain the ID or Name?

Comment: No, These 2 tables have nothing in common

Comment: In that case how do you know Marry is 25 and has a phone? In other words how are you supposed to match `table1` and `table2`?

Comment: What's the relation between the 2 tables? Is it the row number (if so, its a very bad idea!)

Comment: The thing I want to do is trying to export multiple tables into 1 table which fields are concatenated. I don't really care about how these tables are linked together... so is it possible for me to do it?

Comment: Does it matter if all rows have 25 as age and Marry as name?

Comment: I can think of one solution at the moment: add one more column named `index` auto increment, then do a join. Do you think it is possible? Because what is need is clearly shown on the example, then whatt @vhu said is similar to join, which does a cartesian product and it is totally not what I need here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT @n1:=@n1+1 as 'index', Table1.*  FROM Table1, (select @n1:=0)t)t1 
        natural join (SELECT @n2:=@n2+1 as 'index', Table2.*  FROM Table2, (select @n2:=0)t1)t2 ;
```

You can see in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77dcb/4) a working example.

In the example we generate an **index** column for *Table1* and *Table2* and `natural join` the 2 tables.

This way the join is done using the row position as returned by the `SELECT` of tables without any `ORDER` operator and usually **this is not a good idea!**

Comment: You should be aware that, while usually in natural order, the order of data return by a select (without an order by) is not guaranteed. see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/why-is-ssms-inserting-new-rows-at-the-top-of-a-table-not-the-bottom/5775#5775. If there are gaps in the ID in Table1 then there will be a problem too.

Comment: if there is a gap in table 1, a null value would be expected to be there, I would add this to my question to make this clear

Comment: What do you mean with a _gap_? a row with a `null` *ID* or row with *ID* = 4 and no row with *ID* =3 ?

Comment: @Trung I edited the solution to generate index column for both tables

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure you understand what you are asking but sure you can join two tables without really caring on *which* rows will be matched:

```
SET @i1=0;
SET @i2=0;

SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'xyz' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
 FROM (SELECT @i1:=@i1+1 as i1, table1.* FROM table1) AS a
 JOIN (SELECT @i2:=@i2+1 as i2, table2.* FROM table2) b ON (a.i1=b.i2);
```

Comment: See comment above - this is not guaranteed to give consistent results.

Comment: @PaulF: that's the point. OP doesn't care how the rows are matches, hence the first sentence in the answer.

Comment: As far as I understood OP he doesn't care "how" the join is done but the tables are linked in natural row order. I may be wrong on that - OP could advise.